# UIView clips subviews when it should not

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, xcode7

I put an UIView in my viewcontroller in storyboard and then another UIView in the previous one. My second view is not completly in the bounds of the first one. The problem is that even though I have "Clip subviews" set to "NO" it is still clipping. I do not want it to be clipping. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"layer.masksToBounds = NO" seems to work

[image]